# Action nested inside ui:repeat recreates viewscoped bean instead of navigating away

Tags: jsf-2

I have a h:form with two p:commandButtons. One button is nested inside of ui:repeat inside a component.  The button outside of the ui:include seems to navigate properly to the target destination returned by the action method.  However the identical button nested inside of ui:include and ui:repeat appears to reinitialize the view scoped bean instead of navigating to the action destination.  Does anyone have an explanation and a solution or workaround?

The code is roughly this.  mybean is view scoped.

```
<h:form id="myform">
<p:commandButton value="DoIt" action="#{mybean.doit()}" ajax="true"/> <!-- this works! -->
<ui:include src="/sections/util/mycomp.xhtml">
 <ui:param name="backingbean" value="#{mybean}"/>
</ui:include>
</h:form>
```

Here is the component.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                ...
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <ui:repeat value="#{backingbean.mylit}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <p:commandButton value="DoIt" action="#{backinbean.doit()}" ajax="true"/> <!-- this doesn't -->
  </ui:repeat>
</ui:composition>
```

Strangely if I reposition the nested p:commandButton inside the ui:component but outside of the ui:repeat, then it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with any Mojarra version. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Is it MyFaces?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I copied your codes and tried to reproduce the problem but it seems that mine is working OK. By the way, if you want to use that button for navigation probably you should set ajax to false. Below are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="myform">
            <p:commandButton value="DoIt" action="#{backingBean.goToAnotherPage()}" ajax="true"/> <!-- this works! -->
            <ui:include src="firstpage.xhtml">
                <ui:param name="bb" value="#{backingBean}"/>
            </ui:include>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here the second page firstpage.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

            <ui:repeat value="#{bb.myList}" var="item" varStatus="status">
                <p:commandButton value="DoItInRepeat" action="#{bb.goToAnotherPage()}" ajax="true"/> <!-- this doesn't -->
            </ui:repeat>
            <ui:debug hotkey="x" />

</ui:composition>
```

And finally the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean {

    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        myList.add("1");
        myList.add("2");
        myList.add("3");
    }

    public String goToAnotherPage(){
        return "destpage.xhtml";
    }
    //Getters and Setters     
}
```